# Shielding (filtering/absorbing) xrays only

Tags: x-rays, optical-materials

Is there a material that could filter the x-ray wavelengths but leave visible, ultraviolet, and infrared relatively unaltered? Ideal would be something that could be painted on a sheet and placed in front of a lamp.

Comment: http://www.lebowcompany.com/

Comment: http://www.lunduniversity.lu.se/lup/publication/2260940

Answer (score 2):

For the visible there is lead glass (or glass with other heavy elements). Such materials were common in CRT-based color-tv-sets. Similarly, there exist x-ray absorbing plastics that are transparent in the visible.

These compounds are generally absorbing in the ultraviolet.

Anything that absorbs x-rays must be thicker than a layer of paint. The required thickness depends on the photon energy.